# Android - ListView with CheckBoxes get unchecked even when saving states

Tags: android, checkbox

It's been 2 days and I'm beginning to lose hope in my programming abilities.
Here's my `BaseAdapter` :

```
private Context ctx;
private ArrayList<MultiSelectionItem> items;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private boolean[] checked;

// Constructor
public MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<MultiSelectionItem> items) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.items = items;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

    checked = new boolean[items.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        checked[i] = true; // Notice I'm setting all checkboxes to checked !
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MultiSelectionItem item = items.get(position);

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView;
    if (checkBox == null) {
        checkBox = (CheckBox) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_selection_checkbox, parent, false);
    }

    checkBox.setText(item.getLabel());
    checkBox.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // isChecked is always false !!!!
            checked[(Integer) buttonView.getTag()] = isChecked;
        }
    });
    checkBox.setChecked(checked[position]);

    return checkBox;
}
```

CheckBoxes states get stored correctly in `checked` array, **HOWEVER**...
Even though I do `checkBox.setChecked(true)`, `isChecked` parameter in the listener always contains false ! Why is that ?

CheckBox layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Comment: Try my answer below.

Comment: Your adapter is perfectly fine, the fact that you are using it inside `Spinner` makes the difference. `Spinner` automatically deselects other items because usually spinner is supposed to select only one item. Do not loose hope, I will answer shortly with a solution.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using this adapter inside `Spinner` and not `ListView`?

Comment: In the spinner's `onPerformClick` I'm opening a dialog containing a ListView. So the adapter is ListView's not spinner's

Comment: Or if you are using it with `ListView` then make sure you are not using `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

Comment: or from xml `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` instead ? Because I'm hacking the spinner to allow me to select multiple choices

Comment: @M-WaJeEh * *tearful hug* * indeed the problem was the setting of `CHOICE_MODE`. I removed it all at once since the choice mechanism is handled in the adapter, and now it working. Thanks a lot !!! Now I can't sleep in peace :)

Comment: yes it should be multiple or nothing at all, I asked check if you are *not* using `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`, let me post it as answer so others could benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter is perfectly fine, if your `ListView`'s item is just `CheckBox` or anything `Checkable` then you can run into this if your `ListView` is using `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` or `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`.

**Fix** is simple, just don't use any choice mode or use `"multiChoice"` in xml  or `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` from Java code.

But if you are using this adapter with `Spinner` then you will have to trick the `Spinner` that you don't have any `Checkable` root element by placing your `CheckBox` inside some other layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This way `Spinner` will call `setChecked()` on `FrameLayout` and by default check state is not propagated through UI hierarchy so everything will work as expected and you will be able to select more than on item inside `Spinner`'s drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the value to the `Checkbox`  make the listener as null.

```
     checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
     checkBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
     checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // isChecked is always false !!!!
            checked[(Integer) buttonView.getTag()] = isChecked;
        }
    });
     //Your code ............
```

Comment: At that bottom i have written "Your code" it means same as your code.

Comment: @Mehdiway Updated my answer have a look

Comment: Didn't work... in `Your code` there's only `return checkBox` right ?

Comment: Didn't work means ? still same problem is repeating?